# Error in pip install in red hat6 for python2.7.6

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, scapy

In redhat 6 i have upgraded python version python2.7.6 and it has successfull installed. but when i trying to install "pip" for python package installation it is giving error that, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFMti.jpg)

I used some following command that i get in internet..
  #curl "http://bootstap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
  # python get-pip.py
 and after get error of zlib package, i have installed that also. but i dont know to configure it with python
please help me... thanks in advance....

Comment: However you installed python2.7, you also need to install a corresponding pip2.7 with a similar method.

Comment: thanks bro.. but still i a getting same problem when i run few command as.( # python --version)  return " python 2.7.6" after that when i tried (# python2.7 get-pip.py)  i get error " zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available"